# EF DbSet.Find throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities connected by TPT inheritance pattern:

```
public class User {...}
public class Employee : User {...}
```

As you can see, base class isn't abstract so both entity types can be added into db-sets. There are two separate sets (I need them both in my model):

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

So, basically, `Users` table contains all entities and `Employees` holds additional data only for objects that were instantiated as `new Employee()`.

Now, when I try to get entity from `Employees` set using `Find` method, I'm expecting that it will only return 'actual' employees. But if I'm specifying Id of the User entity, EF still fetches it from the database and then throws an `InvalidOperationException`:

> "The specified cast from a materialized
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_B2E5EC989E36BE8C53B9285A70C4E879F0B5672E1D141B93FD299D1BA60258EE'
>   type to the 'Data.Employee' type is not valid."

It can't cast User to Employee, which is understandable.

My question is - is there a way to configure TPT inheritance so Find just returns null in such cases as it does when you pass non-existing Id into it.

My current workaround is this:

```
public Employee GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
    try
    {
        return Employees.Find(id);
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex) when (ex.Message.StartsWith("The specified cast from a materialized"))
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I don't like how it looks - so maybe there is a better (more elegant) solution?

Comment: TPT doesn't mean that you're exposing 2 `DbSet`s. It means you have one `DbSet<User>` that is being splitted **in the database** using TPT hierarchy. You're then supposed to use `OfType<Employee>()` to query for `Employee` only.

Comment: In this case i can't use Find(). In my understanding, Find has better performance results than First/SingleOrDefault().

Comment: Try `this.Set<Employee>().Find(id);` then

Comment: Set<Employee>() is what instantiating DbSet<Employee> object in first place. How it differs from what i'm using currently?

Comment: It *may* differ since it is created dynamically. Maybe your current `Employees` property that is defined statically is behaving differently than `Set<Employee>()` but the odds are close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to prefer singleordefault()/firstordefault() over find as it will return null directly if no matches are found, but could you use a predicate with Find like this?

```
return Employees.Find(em => em.id == id && em is Employee);
```

Comment: Find() can only take primary key values as parameters. There are no other overloads.

Comment: Ah of course ! dbSet!. Guess you could use Cast<User>() to cast to the base object first.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing your DbContext instance. You can't search on the Table Type coz thats declaration.

```
var checkfind = dbInstance.Employees.Find(searchedID);
```

If you don't have access directly to your Db you use

```cs
    using (DBLocal db = new DBLocal())
{
    db.Employees.Find(searchedID);
}
```